# Solve function on Assembler

Tags: assembly

I am dummy in Assembler.
I need to solve next function y=x^2(a+b+c);
a,b,c - input from console
result x is necessary to write in file.
I don't asking to solve this for me but maybe someone share with me useful links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to code something. You might even code a function in C and look at the generated assembler code (e.g. with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm` if using GCC on Linux).

Comment: Is there a tool to generate assembler code from other top-level languages on Windows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably yes. At least GCC is available thru mingw & cygwin, and generated assembly. And there is probably some switch on your compiler to show assembly code too...

Comment: Free Pascal generates assembler from Pascal/delphi

Answer (score 0):

The problem with assembly is that there is no real input and output functions. In a standard programming language you define what you want to appear on the screen. In your case X, and you define what you want the user to input, in your case, a, b, c. Then you do some processing and assign the result to the value x to be output.

All of those steps in standard programming languages, in this specific case, map clearly to a few functions.

Output is done with Print, puts, printf, or writeline ect. These are output functions.
Input is done with Input, gets, or readline ect. These are input functions.
Processing is done with various assignments and decisions. In your case Y (=) X(^)2(*)(a(+)B(+)C)

All simple in a high level language. Taking any part of this for example. In assembly there are at least 3 ways to do pretty much everything. None of them easy. Using DOS interrupts, Using BIOS interrupts, and Using direct hardware interrupts. So at least 3 ways to do Output, and 3 more to do input and then there is the goofing around with memory to do the calculations.

Dont misunderstand, it is well worth the adventure to learn how to do it. I am making it sound a lot harder than it actually is. You are still talking about at least 4 to 5 lines of code for each part of your program. However, once done, you can reuse them to output and input any number of things just like a standard programming language. With one execption, you have full control over the whole lot.

Unfortunately, there is no easy ways to learn assembly. But you are asking the right questions.

1. How do I get some output on the screen
2. How do I get some input from the keyboard
3. How do I do some processing like x+y-z

I know this does not answer your questio on how to do it. However, I will be surprised if you get the answer you are looking for here without posting some assembly code that you have tried to write first.